# Using "lein ring server" over SSH with Datomic and a GPG key

Tags: clojure, gnupg, datomic

Leiningen will not ask me for my passphrase to decrypt my gpg key (which has my username and pass for Datomic).

```
gpg --quiet --batch --decrypt ~/.lein/credentials.clj.gpg
```

Prompts for a password in a terminal/ascii-like "popup" (and subsequently gives me the decrypted key) but then trying

```
lein deps
```

or

```
lein ring server-headless 4000
```

Simply says

```
$ lein ring server-headless 4000
Could not decrypt credentials from /home/vas/.lein/credentials.clj.gpg
gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available

See `lein help gpg` for how to install gpg.
```

Even though I never cancel nor input my passphrase.  Same operation works on my local machine no problem, although it gives me a graphical popup for the password.  Is there a way to force a terminal-based passphrase entry?

I'm talking through SSH with another ubuntu box and I'd like to know how to make it prompt for a password or maybe another way I could get it to work.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:  https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/615

It looks like the solution is to use Keychain.

https://github.com/funtoo/keychain

Comment: Yes, using a keychain fixes this. Sadly lein doesn't play nicely with the tty using gpg. Also, you can forward a local keychain (tied to your local login) over ssh.

Comment: @noisesmith Could you illuminate how the latter (forwarding a local keychain over SSH) is possible?  I'm having trouble having keychain store a semi-persistent session.  If I understand it right, I could do the gpg --batch --etc... command and have the passphrase tty popup ask me for the pass, then I could do the lein command and keychain should have it more-or-less cached for that operation?  That was my theory but it still is not working. Thank you for your reply

Comment: I answered the specific question about gpg, but thinking about the bigger picture for a moment, it's best not to use lein on production (it's a build and dev tool after all), and use environment variables rather than a credentials file on the server. Use an uberjar to run the app. Among other reasons, this allows faster startup, more consistency, and the ability to automate deployment.

Comment: noisesmith you're a genius.  I wouldnlike a repl to talk with my database remotely but the app can run purely from an uberjar... Will ponder

Comment: You can run a repl from an uberjar (either via the clojure.main class, or via the nrepl library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options here, but the best one is to [use the Unix Domain Socket forwarding](https://superuser.com/a/884602) feature of openssh, and then use a proper gpg agent locally.